# How to parse More than one web services one by one and listview using JSON

Tags: android

I am developing media related application in that I need to call more than one web services one by one and list out this elements using cardview with Recycleview. Anyone can suggest me for that issu.

Thanks in advance.
Arasu

Comment: I don't know how to use multiple web services in a single activity or else i need to use String[] url={..., ....., ....., ....}; just like it.

Answer (score 1):

If i get it correctly you have to call several WS and get the data. Well you can do it using for example Volley or OkHttp that handles async requests.

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
   Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
   client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            // notify error
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
          // parse the data
        }
      }
   });
```

When you have the data ready you update the model behind the recyclerview and show the new info.
If you have problems with RecyclerView you can create a layout like this:

```
   <RelativeLayout >
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/cardList"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

and each row holds a card (row layout):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/card_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp">
     .....
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can give a look at my post that shows [how to use RecyclerView and CardView](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/11/a-guide-to-android-recyclerview-cardview.html).
Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the new items as they are received from those web services to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to make the new items show up in the `Recyclerview`. Something like -

```
if(mAdapter == null) {
   // First item received, adapter not initialized yet.
   mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
   mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
   // Adapter already exists. Add received items to the adapter.
   mAdapter.add(items);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```